# Uploading Images to cloud while using app Inventor for Android

Tags: android, cloud, image-uploading, app-inventor, image-upload

I am not able to device a way to upload images to any of the cloud services from an app Inventor project. My use case is to take snap from one install of the app and should be accessible to other install of the app [on a different phone with a different user].

Until now I have looked into : http://puravidaapps.com/drive.php

But this tutorial only explains to access gDrive of the user which would be separate account.

I have also looked into imgur APIs but they need the image to be converted in base64 format.

In short, any of following answers should solve my purpose.

1) Getting gDrive to work without user asking to do the authentication to the app's service account

--> Any link to achieve this would be very helpful as I am lost in documentation and somewhere it clearly says that it only supports OAuth 2 authentication, which I understand that the user will have to use their own account information

2) The APIs from imgur and other such image hosting services needs the image to be converted to base64

--> Is making a separate procedure using the file component following https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 is only option or I can get it converted using some other service too.

**EDIT** : I see that it is not possible to parse the image contents using any of the components in app inventor

3) I also think that it easy to get and upload images to an ftp server. I am yet to see a free ftp service.

4) Is there any other way I can do it.

I am emphasizing on free services because my app is free and for a social cause.

Any inputs and suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use my [Google Drive interface](https://puravidaapps.com/drive.php) also without login, in this case the images will be uploaded to your Google Drive, see my example app, which is available in the Download section there
2. There is currently no block, which converts an image into base64, but you could write your own extension and create a block yourself. More information about how to create an extension see the [announcement](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/Ip2AX036d0U/5NJlAEbFCgAJ), 
   however that will be more advanced and will require some Java skills...
3. I can offer my [App Inventor FTP extension](https://puravidaapps.com/ftp.php)
4. Other ways to upload images (there might be more):
   a) uploading to your web server, see my [postfile example](https://puravidaapps.com/postfile.php)
   b) uploading to Dropbox, see my [Dropbox example](https://puravidaapps.com/dropbox.php)

> I am emphasizing on free services because my app is free and for a
>   social cause.

You might want to read a little bit about [TANSTAAFL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TANSTAAFL)...